# Why does polygon disappear in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation

I am new to the whole QGIS platform but have worked out adding layers, shapefiles, polygons etc. and the rest of the simple stuff. But just now the polygon I am trying to add disappears when I right click at the end.

Weirder though is when I first right click it's as if I have clicked somewhere way off the canvas. I am confused as I have been doing this simply for the past couple weeks. No hassle.

I am working with QGIS 2.14.17.

Comment: How are you trying to add a polygon and to what? It's possible that you're extended outside the domain of the feature class (layer), possibly you have your spatial reference incorrectly defined, or you may be self-intersecting the polygon and the topology checker is voiding your edit.

Comment: So i am just wanting to add a basic polygon as a study area over an aerial. I am starting with a blank canvas, adding Google Satellite from 'Web" in taskbar then 'open layers plugin'. I then zoom to my desired location add shapefile, choose polygon, name it, add to field, save in desired area etc. Then choose editing tool, add feature. When i first left click it joins way off canvas. When it comes to right clicking at the end the feature attribute ID box appears and i name it only for it to dissapear and no attributes are recorded.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're adding a polygon to a layer with an existing styling. When R-clicking and creating the feature, it gets the styling applied, thus if you do not enter the styling field attribute, or add the wrong data, it is simply not displayed.

Try adding the "other" or "blank" category to your styles, and opening the attribute table to see if the feature actually exists when you save it.

Comment: Do you mean in the feature attribute box? Polygon dissapears as i right click. What do you mean by adding the "other" or "blank" category to your styles? Apologies for the ignorance - this has me perplexed and i don't really know the ins and outs of a lot of it. I just knew how to do my few things and now i can't

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was using a wrong coordinate system. Rightclick on the polygon and click on properties. There you can read about the necessary coordinate system.